# do not allow a directory to be deleted but make new files in it?

Tags: permissions, directory

The question in my assignment says this:

> create a directory temp with all permissions for everybody, that
>   cannot be deleted
>
> and copy hello.sh in this directory giving execution rights for
>   everybody, but hello.sh will be executed as the owner.

So I created a directory called temp and gave permissions like this:

```
chmod 555 temp
```

but when I try to cp hello.sh to temp I get an error as temp has the permissions 555. What does the professor exactly meant to ask here? How do I not allow a directory to be deleted but copy files into it?

Comment: What do you mean `prof`?  Secondly who should not be able to delete the directory?

Answer (score 7):

Given that this is a homework assignment I won't give an exact answer but think about this: if you were given this assignment, that means that the `setuid` and `sticky` bits have been explained to you.  That knowledge should be sufficient to complete this assignment.

Comment: thank you, I looked at sticky bit and setuid as soon as I saw your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Linux splits the permission settings into 3 groups:

- Owner - The user who owns the file
- Group - Set of users
- World - Not owner and not part of Group

Following permission can be granted:

- Read
- Write
- Execute

You can use `chmod` command to set the permissions for each group (`Owner/User/World`) by applying desired (`Read/Write/Execute`) tags to each one of them. The digits which are used to set the permissions are actually the decimal representation of the binary (`0/1`) flags which set per group. For example, you want to set permissions which will allow the following:

- Owner - read, write and execute
- Group - read and execute (but not write)
- World - no permissions

So in that case for `Owner` we will have: `read=1`, `write=1` and `execute=1` resulting in permission:

```
111 -> 7
```

The `Group` will have: `read=1`, `write=0` and `execute=1` resulting in permission:

```
101 -> 5
```

And finally the `World` will have: `read=0`, `write=0` and `execute=0` resulting in permission:

```
000 -> 0
```

Additionally, you can set a what is called the **sticky bit** to a directory. It will prevent other users from deleting or renaming the files within that directory. Only the owner can delete or rename the files within that directory. So in your case, the correct `chmod` command will look like this:

```
chmod 1777 temp
```

Where `777` allows `read/write/execute` for all three groups and the additional `1` is the **sticky bit**.

Comment: None of this seems to explain how you could make a directory that's writable but not deletable

Comment: @Michael Mrozek You're right. Modified my answer.

Comment: `110` -> `6` not `5`.

Comment: @EugeneS Thank you very much for your time to explain all this.

Comment: @Karlson My mistake. Fixed!

Comment: @varchar1 You are welcome. Hope that helps!